# Image creating functions not working on https

Tags: php, image

I am working on project on php and created a module for cropping a image. My code for cropping image is:

```html
$targ_w = 400;
$targ_h = 400;
$jpeg_quality = 90;
$src = "PATH_OF_ORIGINAL_IMAGE";
$filename = pathinfo($src);
$extension = $filename['extension'];
if($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'jpeg')
{
 $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
if($extension == 'png')
{
 $img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
if($extension == 'gif')
{
 $img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);
}
$dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );
$imageName = "cropped.jpeg";
imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,600,600,$targ_w,$targ_h,600,600);
$path = "PATH_FOR_NEW_IMAGE".$imageName;
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,$path,$jpeg_quality);
```

This code is working great and cropping image with provided details. But I had moved my website from http to https, This code stops working. No error is displaying and creating image. But images are blank and black image. When I moved website back to http it's again starts working. But I want my website to be on https. I have two questions and they are:

1. Why is the created image blank?
2. If it's server issue how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure there are not errors?
Have you tried with error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
The src is a local path or an url?

Comment: It's showing error Message:  imagecreatefrompng(): problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your answer I think you are loading your `$src` from an url.

I would try downloading the file before manipulating it, like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create(["ssl" => [
  "verify_peer"      => false,
  "verify_peer_name" => false]
]);

$fileContent = file_get_contents($src, false, $context);
```

Then you can create your image with:

```
$img_r = imagecreatefromstring($fileContent);
```

Without checking the extension, it will return a valid image resource or false if the content of the string is not an image. 
With this method you avoid also errors occurring where a png image is renamed with jpg extension.

**Note** that you are disabling ssl check and it could be a security hole.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider handling the cropping (and perhaps other image manipulation operations) via a service that can also serve the processed image using HTTPS to your users via a fast CDN? e.g. http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration#display_and_manipulate_images